# Brain structures related to risk-taking behavior

Tags: neuroscience, abnormal-psychology, personality, neuroimaging

I did a preliminary research on brain structures in which activity might underlie risk-taking behavior. I came to two research that described **right prefrontal cortex** (Knoch et al., 2006), or **orbitofrontal cortex** in relation to **accumbens** (Galvan et al., 2006) as the structures that might be involved. What are other brain structures that might be related to this kind of behavior ? And is there any integrated theories about
the structures involved ?

**References**

Galvan, A., Hare, T. A., Parra, C. E., Penn, J., Voss, H., Glover, G., & Casey, B. J. (2006). Earlier development of the accumbens relative to orbitofrontal cortex might underlie risk-taking behavior in adolescents. The Journal of Neuroscience, 26(25), 6885-6892.

Knoch, D., Gianotti, L. R., Pascual-Leone, A., Treyer, V., Regard, M., Hohmann, M., & Brugger, P. (2006). Disruption of right prefrontal cortex by low-frequency repetitive transcranial magnetic stimulation induces risk-taking behavior. The Journal of neuroscience, 26(24), 6469-6472.

Comment: Hi Ehsan.  I'm withholding my vote to close this question to give you time to do some initial research and increase the quality and content of this question.

Comment: @KeeganKeplinger Thanks, I will!

Comment: FWIW, you can reopen your question after editing it if it does get put on hold (or even closed) in the meantime. Also, IMO, there is no valid reason to close as is: this is clear, not opinion-based, and not *necessarily* too broad (you're not asking for **all** the brain structures *plus references* after all)...SE policy in general is to downvote for lack of initial research, not to close, if that's the only complaint.